# How to find previous element in jQuery on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My button is in a TD and I want to just previous TD on button click event I am doing it following but not getting the value... How should I do it?

```
$(".prodcs").click(function () {
        var test = $(this).attr(".prodcs").prev().find('#DDL option:selected').val();
        alert(test);
        CustomCategory.OnCustomClick($(this).attr("data-productid"));
    });
```

Below is the HTML

```
<tr>
                        <td width="170">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1">
                        </td>
                        <td width="560">
<select name="DDL" id="DDL" class="form-control"><option value="1">7''  - £10.00</option>
<option value="2">14'' - £15.00</option>
<option value="6">5''  - £5.00</option>
<option value="7">500 M- £15.00</option>
</select>                        </td>
                        <td width="102" align="right">

                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-productid="3" id="product_3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg popup prodcs">Customisation</a>

                        </td>
                        <td width="101" align="right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 20px; color: #666"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one element with an id of `DDL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `.prodcs` is the button

```
$(".prodcs").click(function () {
    var test = $(this).closest("td").prev().find('select').val();
    alert(test);
    CustomCategory.OnCustomClick($(this).attr("data-productid"));
});
```

- [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used to find the td in which the button is present
- [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) finds the previous td element
- [.find('select')](http://api.jquery.com/find/) finds the select element inside the previous td

Note: If there are multiple elements with the id `DDL`, it is not valid use a class instead

Comment: There are multiple DLL but we are finding it specific to that button click and just the previous TD of button TD...will it fail ever..

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet no but in html ID of an element must be unique so it will be better to use a class instead of an ID for a repeated element

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $(".prodcs").click(function () {
        var test = $(this).parent().prev().find('#DDL option:selected').val();
        alert(test);
        CustomCategory.OnCustomClick($(this).attr("data-productid"));
    });
```

or

```
   $(".prodcs").click(function () {
        var test = $(this).closest('td').prev().find('#DDL option:selected').val();
        alert(test);
        CustomCategory.OnCustomClick($(this).attr("data-productid"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there just remove **.attr(".prodcs")**:

```
var test = $(this).prev().find('#DDL option:selected').val();
```